# HTML Select DropDown list with multiple colours

Tags: html, colors, html-select

Is it possible to have different colours for different items in the dropdown list?

For example:

Option 1 = green
Option 2 = blue
etc

Comment: Yes possible, use class or id in option tag by css

Answer (score 19, accepted):

here is what you want [Styling Dropdown Lists](http://www.outfront.net/tutorials_02/adv_tech/funkyforms5.htm)

```html
    <style type="text/css">
    option.red {background-color: #cc0000; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px;}
    option.pink {background-color: #ffcccc;}
    </style>

    <select name=colors>
    <option class="red" value= "../getting_started/">Getting Started </option>
    <option class="pink" value= "../getting_started/html_intro1.htm">- Intro to HTML
     </option>
    </select>
```

Comment: What if I'm filling the dropdown list from a list in this way:

'@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ModActionCatList, actionCatList, new { @class = "select2-select-00 col-md-12 full-width-fix required" ...'

Comment: Maybe someone can help clear up some confusion, I looked up `<Style tyle=` but got no hits.  I just tested this and the color works as desired even if you remove `tyle` leaving the first line to read `<style =text/css>`

Answer (score 4):

CSS and HTML

```css
#option-1 {
  color: red;
}
#option-2 {
  color: green;
}

#option-3 {
  color: yellow;
}

#option-4 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option id="option-1">Option 1</option>
  <option id="option-2">Option 2</option>
  <option id="option-3">Option 3</option>
  <option id="option-4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean a `select`? This should work:

```
option:nth-child(1) { background: green; }
option:nth-child(2) { background: blue; }
```

etc

Comment: Sadly `:nth-child` doesn't work in IE (and there are problems with it in some other browsers).

Comment: It is a CSS3 selector which is still under development and not properly implemented in all majors browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <label>Job Status:</label>
                        <select type="text" name="fname" class="form-control"  placeholder="Job Status" >
                                <option value="">Select Status</option>
                                <option class="btn btn-success"  value="Working">Working</option>
                                <option class="btn btn-warning"  value="In Proccess">In Proccess</option>
                                <option class="btn btn-danger" value="Closed">Closed</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person who's asking. Consider editing your answer to add an explanation and/or some more insight on why your solution is better than other ones. See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).