# Change color in select option - HTML/CSS/JQuery - Mac

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the text colour of several options in select dropdown.

I don't care about which one is selected. I just want the user to see, when opening the dropdown menu, some options as yellow (in this example).

```
<select>
   <option>Black</option>
   <option>Black</option>
   <option style="color: rgb(255, 255, 0);">Yellow</option>
</select>
```

[This is my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h84kx65f/)

Other solutions in Stackoverflow haven't worked for me in Chrome 59.

I also want to be able to change the colour of the options with Javascript/JQuery like so:

```
var option = AJS.$('<option>', {...});
option.css("color", "#2ee4ff");
```

I can't manage to make the colours work at all, however.

Comment: Are you using Mac by any chance ?

Comment: Your provided fiddle works for me. The text in the dropdown is yellow. What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Mac. It's not working for me :(

Comment: No problem to report here too. Works both on Chrome 59 and Firefox 54 under Windows 10.
You should dig the way of a Mac related issue I guess.

Comment: try with another browser

Comment: What does a Mac have to do with the question?

Comment: Is there a solution that works for all OSs?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720532/html-select-dropdown-list-with-multiple-colours try this

Comment: Hi, @pavlos163 Were you able to find any solution for the above mentioned issue on MAC? I am also facing the same issue..

Comment: @pavlos163 Sorry to bother you again, but can you kindly let me know if you were able to find a working solution on MAC. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Learner, it's been a long time since then, but I don't think I found a solution for this!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```js
$("select option").each(function(){
 value=$(this).val();
  $(this).css("color",value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option>Black</option>
<option>Black</option>
<option>Yellow</option>
</select>
```

Comment: No, this is not working either. I see all options as black.

Answer (score 0):

I got frustrated with the possibilities to style a select box a long time ago and created an alternative. Maybe this helps you.

It uses a `ul` to display the options and stores the chosen value in the `div` being displayed on the screen and the `input` tag for further processing.

```js
$("body").on("click", ".selected", function() {
  $(this).next(".options").toggleClass("open");
});

$("body").on("click", ".option", function() {
  var selected = $(this).find("span").html();
  $(".selected").html(selected);
  $("input[name='mySelect']").val(selected);
  $(".options").toggleClass("open");
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 25%;
}

.selected {
  border: thin solid darkgray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: .2em;
  padding-left: .5em;
  min-width: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

.selected:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f0d7";
  margin-left: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  right: .5em;
}

.options {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.options.open {
  display: inline-block;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li>img {
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.yellow {
  color: yellow;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <form>
  <input type="hidden" name="mySelect" value="">
  <div class="selected">Select an option</div>
  <ul class="options">
    <li class="option yellow"><span>Option 1</span></li>
    <li class="option"><span>Option 2</span></li>
    <li class="option blue"><span>Option 3</span></li>
  </ul>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not using a `select` tag.