# Multiple color in HTML option tag (combobox)

Tags: css, html, html-select

I need a way to use two colors in the html option tag. For this I wrote the following code:

```html
<select>
<option><span style="color: red;">color red1</span> - default color1</option>
<option><span style="color: red;">color red2</span> - default color2</option>
<option><span style="color: red;">color red3</span> - default color3</option>
</select>
```

As you can see, the color styling doesn't work. So is there a way for using multiple colors in an option tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change select box option background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836227/how-to-change-select-box-option-background-color)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Select DropDown list with multiple colours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720532/html-select-dropdown-list-with-multiple-colours)

Comment: What do you want your dropdown to look like? You should be applying the style to the option element. Maybe you are wanting to use background-color instead of color- I'm not really sure what the end goal is

Comment: The end goal is to have in one option tag two different colors

Comment: ... the text to be different colors?  for "color red" to be red and "default color" to be a different color?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to move the `style` attr to the option element.
Also advised, use a class vs. inline styling for re-usability.

Also Note: Inputs/Selects/Checkboxes etc all have browser specific styling. Keep this in mind when developing for multi browser support.

**UPDATE 1**: Apologies on missing the end-goal. Unfortunately the option element cannot have child elements and styling as such will fail.

A way around this is build your own `select` element using standard `<div>` elements

`<div>Some Text<span> - Second Text</span><div>`

[Example of Custom Select from W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp)

```css
.twoTone {
  color: black;
}
.twoTone span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<select>
<!-- Does Not work because options cannot have child elements -->
<option class='twoTone'><span>color red1</span> - default color1</option>
<option><span style="color: red;">color red2</span> - default color2</option>
<option><span style="color: red;">color red3</span> - default color3</option>
</select>

<!-- Works because divs allow child elements -->
<div class='twoTone'><span>Red Text -</span> Black Text </div>
```

Comment: In your sample is the full option text red, but I need a way to style one part of the option text with red color and the other one with black. So the end goal is to have in one option tag two different colors.

Comment: @MartinSchagerl, Updated answer with explanation. Will update snip with a 'home-made' solution if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
<style >
option.red{background-color: red; }
option.blue{background-color: blue;}
</style>

<select name=colors>
<option class="red" >red</option>
<option class="blue">blue</option>
</select>
```

The problem there was the span, I think even if you put the inline style to the options it should work, but I've never done it that way.